# best way to set a bitset with boolean values

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset

Suppose I have 3 `bool` type values

```
bool canwalk=true;
bool cantalk=false;
bool caneat=false;
```

I would like to set a `bitset` denoting the three

```
std::bitset<3> foo;
```

How can I construct a `bitset` using the boolean values?
I want to do something like this

```
 std::bitset<3> foo(canWalk,cantalk,caneat); //giving me 100
```

Comment: It’s a shame `std::bitset` doesn’t have a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list<bool>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the example of Shivendra Agarwal, but using the constructor that receive an `unsigned long long`, I propose the following variadic template function (to be more generic)

```
template <typename ... Args>
unsigned long long getULL (Args ... as)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   unsigned long long ret { 0ULL };

   (void) unused { 0, (ret <<= 1, ret |= (as ? 1ULL : 0ULL), 0)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

that permit the initialization of `foo` as follows

```
std::bitset<3> foo{ getULL(canwalk, cantalk, caneat) };
```

This works only if the dimension of the `std::bitset` isn't grater of the number of bits in an `unsigned long long` (with `3` whe are surely safe).

The following is a full working example

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Args>
unsigned long long getULL (Args ... as)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   unsigned long long ret { 0ULL };

   (void) unused { 0, (ret <<= 1, ret |= (as ? 1ULL : 0ULL), 0)... };

   return ret;
 }

int main()
 {
   bool canwalk=true;
   bool cantalk=false;
   bool caneat=false;

   std::bitset<3> foo{ getULL(canwalk, cantalk, caneat) };

   std::cout << foo << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Why use `unsigned long long` as a temporary? Why not just create the bitset and then assign?

Comment: @MooingDuck - well... I liked the Shivendra Agarwal's answer but I've found it a little heavy; so I've developed a lightweight version of it; the "just create the bitset and then assign" is the other my answer (and, yes:I think it's better)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, an initialization of type

```
std::bitset<3> foo(canWalk, cantalk, caneat);
```

is dangerous (error prone) because require that the template argument of `std::bitset` (`3`, in the example) correspond to the number of argument of the initialization.

I propose the creation of a "make" function (following the consolidated example of `std::pair()`, `std::tuple()`, `std::make_unique()`, `std::make_shared`) where the type and the number of arguments fix the returned type.

So I propose the following `makeBitSet()` function that return a `std::bitset<N>` where `N` is the number of the arguments

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::bitset<sizeof...(Args)> makeBitSet (Args ... as)
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   std::bitset<sizeof...(Args)>  ret;

   std::size_t ui { ret.size() };

   (void) unused { true, (ret.set(--ui, as), true)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

The function can be used as follows

```
std::bitset<3> foo{ makeBitSet(canwalk, cantalk, caneat) };
```

but also (better, IMHO), using the C++11 `auto`,

```
auto foo = makeBitSet(canwalk, cantalk, caneat);
```

Observe that, starting from C++14, `makeBitSet()` can use the returning `auto` type

```
template <typename ... Args>
auto makeBitSet (Args ... as)
 {
   // ...
```

avoiding the annoying `std::bitset<sizeof...(Args)>` redundancy.

Moreover, starting from C++17, you can use template folding and, throwing away the `unused` array (and the corresponding `using` declaration), the `makeBitSet()` can be simplified as [EDIT: modified, to improve performances, following a suggestion from Mooing Duck (thanks!)]

```
template <typename ... Args>
auto makeBitSet (Args ... as)
 {
   std::bitset<sizeof...(Args)>  ret;

   std::size_t ui { ret.size() };

   ( ret.set(--ui, as), ... );

   return ret;
 }
```

The following is a full working C++11 example

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Args>
std::bitset<sizeof...(Args)> makeBitSet (Args ... as)
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   std::bitset<sizeof...(Args)>  ret;

   std::size_t ui { ret.size() };

   (void) unused { true, (ret.set(--ui, as), true)... };

   return ret;
 }

int main()
 {
   bool canwalk { true  };
   bool cantalk { false };
   bool caneat  { false };

   auto foo = makeBitSet(canwalk, cantalk, caneat);

   std::cout << foo << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: It may be dangerous, but it is standard o not fix the length. both c-style arrays and std::array allow it. I wonder why they don't use or recommend this approach for std::array?

Comment: @GemTaylor: c-style arrays have backwards compatibility that appears to have received precedence from null terminated strings, and `std::array` is a trivial type that is only the thinnest of wrappers around a c-style array, and part of the magic it works with is that _it has no constructor_, and so it defaults to only constructing the c-style array, using the legacy syntax. Adding a limiting constructor would break the magic.

Comment: Prefer [bitset.set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/set/) to `bitset.operator[]`, there's a huge performance win sometimes. Not sure how easy that is here.

Comment: @MooingDuck - I didn't know... but make sense: the not constant version of `operator[]` return a `std::bitset::reference` and the following assignment pass through this class. Yes: `set()` is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a new api that can give you string input that bitset accepts in parameter.

to be more generic, recommendation will be to use bool array or `[std::vector<bool>][1]` to get rid of these variable parameters in getString()

```
inline std::string getString(bool canwalk, bool canTalk, bool canEat)
{
std::stringstream input;
str << canwalk?1:0 << cantalk?1:0 << caneat?1:0;
return input.str();
}
```

now can define bitset as:

```
std::bitset<3> foo (getString(canwalk, canTalk, canEat));
```

Comment: casting through string uses unnecessary overhead

Comment: well bitset provided a string constructor for some reason!   and just to add we are using stringstream not string while construction, which is quite optimized for scenarios like these where we may want to append strings.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a builder that will build an initial value from your boolean set to pass to the constructor of std::bitset. You can do this at compile time (as opposed to runtime) via variadic templates, like so:

```
template <unsigned long long initialValue> 
constexpr unsigned long long bitset_value_builder_impl() { return initialValue; }

template <unsigned long long initialValue, typename First, typename ... Args>
constexpr unsigned long long bitset_value_builder_impl(First &&first, Args &&...args) {
    return first ? 
        bitset_value_builder_impl< (initialValue | (1UL<<sizeof...(args)) ), Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) :
        bitset_value_builder_impl< (initialValue & ~(1UL<<sizeof...(args)) ), Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename First, typename ... Args>
constexpr unsigned long long bitset_value_builder(First &&first, Args &&...args) {   
    return bitset_value_builder_impl<0, First, Args...>(std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    bool canwalk=true;
    bool cantalk=false;
    bool caneat=false;    
    std::bitset<3> bits{bitset_value_builder(canwalk, cantalk, caneat)};
    std::cout << bits << std::endl; //100
}
```